# How to get max_array_size?

Tags: hpc, pbs, qsub, torque

I am trying to submit a large job array to a cluster. The `qsub` request fails with a `Bad job array request error`. I think this is because my job array is too large. How can I read the maximum allowed job array size? I think this is stored in a parameter called `max_array_size`, but I'm not sure.

Note that I am not admin of this cluster. I only have user privileges.

Answer (score 1):

The command to see the server settings is `qmgr -c 'print server'`, so you can execute that and look for the setting or run `qmgr -c 'p s' | grep max_job_array_size` to filter only that line.

Comment: I did that, but there's no line with `max_job_array_size`, or anything that looks like it. Maybe it is using a default value. Got any idea how to get the default value?

Comment: The default value is unlimited.

Answer (score 0):

In the version of PBS I'm using the value to search for is `max_array_size`. You can fetch it with the command:

```
 qmgr -c 'print server max_array_size'
```

[image: screenshot of qmgr command]